# Indexing column for full text search

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have column `col` with data type `CHARACTER VARYING`

I need that index this column as `gin` index. If trying directly set gin index to column, returned error:

`data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gin"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type`

If trying:

```
 create index col_vector 
 on mytable 
 using gin (to_tsvector(col))
```

I got error:  `functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

How to create `gin` index for `CHARACTER VARYING` column ?

p.s. I need this for full text search

Answer (score 21):

Try This Code:

```
CREATE INDEX "name " ON "tablename" USING gin(to_tsvector('english', "columnname"));
```

Comment: Here's the explanation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-tables.html